# Angular not routing to nested router-outlets

Tags: angular

I can't get Angular to route the following scenario involving nested router-outlets. The idea is to have an application-wide banner at the top, followed by a dashboard navigation component which has its own router-outlet to display components. Those components should be able to have their own router-outlets so that (for example, to display a master-detail pattern with master on left and detail on right). I'm able to route a single named outlet, but not a named child outlet within another named outlet.

`AppComponent` contains the primary outlet `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, which is to display `DashboardNavComponent` from a lazy-loaded module. `DashboardNavComponent` contains `<router-outlet name='dashboard'></router-outlet>` which should display the main components. I can get that to work (i.e. routing to 'app/dashboard/user/1' displays the banner, navigation and `UserMasterComponent`. But I have been unable to route to `app/dashboard/user/1/contact` and show the banner, navigation, `UserMasterComponent` and also `Contact` component in the `detail` router-outlet.

These are simplified versions of my routes and I've tried multiple route configurations. I have been able to get it to work by breaking them out into separate 'user/:id/contact' and 'user/:id/profile' routes, but that causes the `DashboardNavComponent` and `UserMasterComponent` to reload on each route change between them. I'm fairly new to Angular, but if they are child routes of 'user/:id' I would assume that it only refreshes the component for final ActivatedRoute (i.e. 'contact' or 'profile').

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes = {
  path: 'app',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    }
  ]
}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes = {
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    component: DashboardNavComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: UserMasterComponent,
        outlet: 'master',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: ContactComponent,
            outlet: 'detail'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: UserMasterComponent,
        outlet: 'master',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: ProfileComponent,
            outlet: 'detail'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

After spending over a full work-day on this the past few days, I solve it within 10 minutes of posting on Stack Overflow :) Hopefully this is helpful to someone as I did not find any issues that clearly documented this solution.

I was unaware that each feature could have one unnamed primary router-outlet and was thinking my entire application could have only one. The solution was to make the root router-outlet of the dashboard feature the primary router-outlet and only assign a name to one router-outlet, the 'detail' one. Then, in the route configuration, I removed any instances of `outlet: 'dashboard'`.

To prevent the `DashboardNavComponent` from reloading on each route change, I also had to nest all my Dashboard routes in a catch-all route.

**Final dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes = {
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardNavComponent, // Set component here to prevent re-load
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'contact',
            component: UserMasterComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                component: ContactComponent,
                outlet: 'detail'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            component: UserMasterComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                component: ProfileComponent,
                outlet: 'detail'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: do you know why does naming both the router-outlet cause the problem ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm assuming that the router assumes there should be a primary router for each feature. It worked fine though until my nesting got too deep.

Comment: feature you mean one module

Comment: Yes, I mean feature module. My Dashboard module is lazy-loaded (my actual code uses a canLoad guard to check that the user is authenticated).

Comment: @BrandonRader if you need a lazy loaded version take a look at this answer : )
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67256920/5726621